# oval shape in android edge is not smooth

Tags: android, shapes

oval shape in android pixelation
I am trying to draw a pixel shape in android using xml

the shape is drawn in the desired oval shape but the the edge of the shape looks pixelated

the code I am trying is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <solid android:color="#ffcfcf" />
    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />
</shape>
```

How can I get smooth edge for the shape from the xml file itself.

I am testing on android jelly bean for testing on older phones, on Lolipop the problem of edges is not present.

Comment: could not understand your question please explain further @abcd

Comment: the shape gets pxielated at the border